# Keycloak Kerberos prevent Login Prompt on Windows

Tags: security, keycloak, kerberos, spnego

I am using Keycloak (RH-SSO) for authentication. Intranet users logged in automatically with Kerberos ticket, users outside of intranet must fill login form. Everything works fine, just there is an anoying login prompt which pops up when there is no kerberos ticket (in other words for outside users). But only on windows, Linux and MAC are OK.
[image]
User can press ESC and is redirected to login page. How can I supress this prompt? This way doesnt work for me, because I cant setup permissions on customers comps. [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69104957/keycloak-kerberos-prevent-login-dialog)

Adding login prompt as parameter seems to force login dialog always, which is not what I want. [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627486/skip-kerberos-sso-authentication-in-keycloak)

Trying to put

> BrowserMatch Windows gssapi-no-negotiate

on apache conf.d doesnt work as well. [solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357010/kerberos-gssapi-ad-authentication-fails)

Cant it be configured somehow on Keycloak side, or wildfly?  The last thing I didnt try is to override Spnego authenticator, but that's what I would rather not do.

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Could users just enter their Kerberos details into the login prompt instead?

Comment: No.. if the user is from internal network, he exists in LDAP and Kerberos is doing the login in background automatically... if the user is outside of internal network, he doesnt have account in LDAP and therefore he cannot enter its credentials, because they simply dont exist. He cant just enter by typing credentials in login form with account in Keycloak (not LDAP federation). Problematic are users that can't use Kerberos ticket, cause Windows is forcing them to enter it. Users with Kerberos ticket logged in without problems automatically